# Factory Girl + Rspec: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I have a simple restaurant class that looks like this:

```
module Restaurant
    class Identity

        attr_reader :name, :location

        def initialize (name, location)
            @name = name
            @location = location
        end

    end
end
```

My factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define  do
    factory :restaurant, :class => Restaurant::Identity do |f|
        f.name "Alfredos"
        f.location "Andheri"
    end
end
```

And my test is written like this:

```
describe Restaurant::Identity do

 subject { build(:restaurant) }

 its(:name) {should_not be_nil}
 its(:location) {should_not be_nil}

end
```

But when I run this, I get

```
  1) Restaurant::Identity name 
     Failure/Error: subject { build(:restaurant) }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
     # ./lib/restaurant.rb:7:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/restaurant_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/restaurant_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Ok so the solution is to use `initialize_with` in your factory girl setup:

```
FactoryGirl.define  do
    factory :restaurant, :class => Restaurant::Identity do |f|
        f.name "Alfredos"
        f.location "Andheri"
        initialize_with { new(name, location) } # add this line
    end
end
```

ref: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction